# html разметка accessibility

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос наверное для тех кто уже пытался улучшить accessibility своего проекта. В общем, есть такая разметка:

```
<main>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <form>
    <article>
      <input>
    </article>
  </form>
</main>
```

Когда я выделаю текст и нажимаю tab, я хочу что бы выбирался мой input, но он игнорирутся и tab проходит вниз, уже за форму. Есть варианты как это фиксится ?

Comment: в Хроме переходит на `input`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у меня ignored в accessibility. Прикрепил скрин.

Comment: Приведите достаточно полный пример, чтобы мы его запустили и увидели, что действительно не переходит. Скрины не помогут никак